# getSingleton( 'admin/session' ) REST compliant alternative

Tags: php, rest, magento, session

I'm extending an installation of Magento with an app that can edit products through REST.

In my Magento installation there is an extension that adds a "created_by" field to my products. 
In the code of this extension I see that it does this with

```
Mage::getSingleton( 'admin/session' )->getUser().
```

However, I create some products using REST, and than the Mage::getSingleton( 'admin/session' )->getUser() does not work since there is no admin/session I assume.

Can anybody help me out? Is there some way I could do it like this:

`Mage::getSingleton( 'REST/session' )->getUser()?`

In another stackoverflow post I found this as an answer, but I have no idea what data I have to send in the $tokenId variable.

```
$tokens = Mage::getModel('oauth/token')->getCollection()->addFilterById($tokenId);
foreach ($tokens as $token) 
{    
echo $token->getCustomerId();
}
```

Comment: What extension adds `created_by` to the API?  I was looking for exactly this the other day.

Comment: The extension was installed by a freelancer, and it is not compatible with the REST or SOAP api... It does function in normal Magento setting however. It's Junaidbhura/Jbmarketplace